# Sed: delete a line in multiline variable

Tags: string, bash, sed

Is there simple equivalent of

```
sed -i '/str/d' /file
```

but for multiline variable?

Or I can use only following

```
var=`echo "$var" | sed "s/str//"`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
var=$(echo "$var" | sed '/str/d')
```

The quotes around `$var` in the subcommand are important for interpolating the newline characters.  Otherwise `$var` would all be on one line.

Comment: Oh, yep. I missed this. Is there difference between `var=$(...)` and `var='...'` (I replaced to ' bacause of message formatting there) ?

Comment: There is no difference between backticks and the `$()` notation .. that I know of .. it's just that the latter is clearer

Comment: @EdMorton based on the `man` page it seems like the only difference is in how it handles some characters

Comment: @ExplosionPills there's also differences in handling nested quotations and there may be others. I don't recall the details right now, google would probably find it or ask the experts at comp.unix.shell newsgroup.

Comment: @EdMorton yes this is important, but I initially meant that there should be no *functional* difference between the two.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - those are functional differences. Not sure where you're coming from. Do you mean just in this example?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - try, for example, `echo $(echo $(echo foo))` vs `echo \`echo \`echo foo\`\``

Comment: @EdMorton no I mean if you use the command substitution syntax as you intend there will be no difference in the execution of the subcommand

Comment: ExplosionPills - I'm sorry I think I'm missing your point but the question @Torrius asked was "Is there difference between `var=$(...)` and `var=\`...\``" and the answer is simply yes, there are differences, see "Command Substitution" in the bash man page for details.

Comment: @EdMorton `echo $(echo $(echo foo))` and `echo \`echo \`echo foo\`\`` are not analogous

Comment: @ExplosionPills that is correct, they are not functionally analogous because of one of the differences between `var=$(...)` and `var=\`...\``.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need sed, echo, and a pipe just to manipulate a string in bash:

```
$ echo "$var" 
foo
str
bar

$ var="${var//str
}" 

$ echo "$var"        
foo
bar
```

man bash.